# Routing in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm relearning PHP and codeigniter but i can't help but notice how ugly my url looks.

So i have a pages controller: Say lets load homepage.

It would look like this:

```
public function home(){
$this->load->view('template/header');
$this->load->view('template/navbar');
$this->load->view('pages/home');
$this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

I guess thats decent as my url will probably look like this:
**http://localhost/ProjectName/index.php/pages/home**

But whenever i click on a link that involves more data processing for example lets say my home has a list of users and i click on one to view their profile. I ofcourse have to pass something to identify which profile i am to load so my link would look like this:

**http://localhost/OnlineStories/index.php/pages/view_userprofile/1**

In my controller id have:

```
public function view_userprofile(){
$userid = $this->uri->segment(3);
//process data then load view
}
```

I'm not asking for any advanced stuff but i would like to ask simple things to improve my url like correct standard for naming my controller functions.

For example: on previous instances of loading my homepage my function name was `view_home` now its simply just `home` so its cleaner.

Maybe i could rename my `view_userprofile` to simply `user_profile`.

Anyway is there any better method to passing values from view to controller other than uri segment? its what ive been using so i never gave it much thought. I've seen some use get() but idk if its better than uri segment?

Or should i stick with the uri segment and keep my url as controller/method/parameter?

I haven't really explored post-project polishing in codeigniter so idk if theres a way to polish/change the url(just the name).

Comment: uri routing: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talk about URL in CodeIgniter, you never mention about `application/config/routes.php` file. Have you seen it ..?

In `routes.php` file you can create your URL name and mapping it to the controller/function that you have

like this:

```
$route['user/update'] = 'user_controller/update_data_function'
```

so, you can call URL `http://your.site/index.php/user/update` to execute your `update_data_function()` in your `User_controller.php`

Comment: I've known about it but i never touched it. I did not want to mess up my project since it's still on-going.

Can you give me a basic run down on what routes can do to the url? just edit your answer and i'll accept it.